Theme change with scss in react
I'm trying to change theme in react project only with scss. The project is already big and I'm trying to find a simple solution to leave all the scss modules untouched. So I'm trying this approach: I'll only change the color variables when theme is changed, for example if on light mode color primary is white, by changing the mode into dark, color primary will be black, so the naming should stay the same and only the values will be changed.
I encountered this css approach, which unfortunately isn't working for scss.
this is the variables folder:
$color-primary-light: #000;
$color-secondary-light: #fff;

$color-primary-dark: #fff;
$color-secondary-dark: #000;

[data-theme="light"] {
  --color-primary: #{$color-primary-light};
  --color-secondary: #{$color-secondary-light};
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --color-primary: #{$color-primary-dark};
  --color-secondary: #{$color-secondary-dark};
}

this is the module scss:
.mainDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: var(--color-secondary);
  color: var(--color-primary);
}

and jic this is tsx file:
const [theme, setTheme] = useState(
    window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "dark" : "light"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setTheme((prevTheme) => (prevTheme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
    console.log("theme");
    
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.mainDiv}>
      <p>SassTest</p>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="theme_switch"
          id="switch"
          checked={theme === "dark"}
          onChange={handleThemeChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="switch">Toggle darkmode</label>
        <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet cake candy dessert.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

Is there a way I use the similar approach in scss and not use css properties, so instead of var(--color-primary) I would write $color-primary in module.scss files?
